# Thick or thin line according to the touch

Tags: ios, core-graphics, draw

I am using the core graphics for drawing in my application.

I would like to draw a thick or thin line based on the touch speed ...

I have wrote the following code for drawing the thick or thin line.

In i was able to trace the velocity using panGestureRecognizer and i have applied it , for line width , as a result i was able to draw thick and thin line  according to the velocity of the touch.

But the Main problem is line which draw is not look like smooth.

So it would be great, if I draw successful thick or thin line in a smooth.

```
- (void)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGestureRecognizer
{

    if (panGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {



        // retrieve touch point
        currentPoint = [panGestureRecognizer locationInView:panGestureRecognizer.view];

        previousPoint = currentPoint;



    }

    if (panGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {

        currentPoint = [panGestureRecognizer locationInView:panGestureRecognizer.view];


        previousPoint = currentPoint; 

        float vel = [self ccpLength:[panGestureRecognizer velocityInView:panGestureRecognizer.view]];

        tmplinewidth    =   vel /   166.0f;

        tmplinewidth    =   clampf(tmplinewidth, 2, 20);


    }

    if (panGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {

    }
}
```